# Most appropriate "2D" representation for storing a string and double value side-by-side in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, containers

I'm looking for a data type that can store both a string and a double for record keeping. The string is some password and the double is some score for that password, determined after the password is inserted into the data structure. What data type would be best for this kind of situation?

So far I've been using `ArrayList`s, one each for each bit of data, but it's coming to the point I need to implement sorting by one part and the logistics don't particularly appeal to me.

For example:

```java
private ArrayList<String> keys = ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<Double> scores = ArrayList<Double>();
// n and m determined at runtime

private void generateKeys(int m, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        keys.add(getRandomKey(n));
    }
}

private String getRandomKey(int n) {
    String key = "";
    String charValues = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    int randIndex;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        randIndex = random.nextInt(26);
        key += charValues.charAt(randIndex);
    }
    return key;
}

private void generateScores() {
    for (int i = 0; i < size(keys); i++) {
        scores.add(findScore(keys.get(i)));
    }
}

private double findScore(String k) {
    // some function
}
```

Example data would be:

```
    key     score
"fsuifshu", 0.950
"wowaflsa", 0.120
"woawfjff", 0.430
"fireplfd", 0.040
...
```

The `key` is inserted first using a loop and random character generator, then the `score` is calculated after every `key` was inserted already. I do want to be able to move them around (sort based on `score`).

Ultimately, I want to be able to sort the keys based on their score. So an expected output based on the aforementioned would be:

```
"fsuifshu"
"woawfjff"
"wowaflsa"
"fireplfd"
```

A sorted ArrayList would contain that, for example.

Comment: How many entries do you expect to store in this data structure? And are you more concerned about memory usage or elegance?

Comment: @JörnHorstmann ease of programming. Not concerned about memory or speed. The number of entries is user defined with no maximum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly disagree with Jason's answer and wouldn't put the data into a map for a few reasons:

1. I believe you should avoid using maps as a lazy way to represent your domain data. I find it much better to create your own domain classes to hold your domain data. You can make much better use of a well defined object, such as easily putting it in other data structures or passing it as an argument to a function, all while being very clear about the data.
2. If, in the future, you need additional metadata about the password, that map data structure would break and need a lot of rework whereas with a domain class you could just add another field with nothing else needing to change.
3. Maps are, in general, not intended to be sorted data structures. There are map structures that maintain insertion order or sort on the keys but sorting on the values is especially odd. You *can* coerce the data to be sorted in any way you want (such as shown [here](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-sort-a-map-by-value-in-java-8)) but I would avoid trying to shoe-horn structures into something they aren't intended for.

Here's an example of what I would do:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<PasswordWithScore> passwords = new ArrayList<>();

        int numberOfPasswords = 5;
        int lengthOfPassword = 5;

        Random rand = new Random();
        String chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPasswords; i++) {
            StringBuilder password = new StringBuilder();
            for (int j = 0; j < lengthOfPassword; j++) {
                password.append(chars.charAt(rand.nextInt(chars.length())));
            }
            passwords.add(new PasswordWithScore(password.toString()));
        }

        passwords.sort(Comparator.comparing(PasswordWithScore::getScore).reversed());
        System.out.println(passwords);
    }
}
```

---

```
/** Your domain class */
public class PasswordWithScore {
    private final String password;
    private final double score;

    public PasswordWithScore(String password) {
        this.password = password;
        this.score = findScore(password);
    }

    public String getPassword() { return password; }
    public double getScore() { return score; }

    @Override public String toString() {
        return password + ":" + score;
    }

    private static double findScore(String password) {
        // but different
        return password.chars().sum();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You want to use a java.util.Map. It stores key-value pairs.

```java
Map<String, Double> map = new HashMap<>();

map.put("foo", 1.0D);
```

Comment: I strongly disagree with this answer. For one, maps are not really intended to be sorted on their values; It is doable, but I believe they shouldn't be shoe-horned into it. OP should use a domain class to represent their data rather than a less clear and less flexible map.

Answer (score 2):

Although map seems appropriate at first sight, I would recommend a separate class since you plan to sort your data.

```
public class MyDataHolder{

     String pass;
     double score;
    // getters & setters
 }
```

You could then store your objects in a list

```
List<MyDataHolder> myEntries;
```

And sort by either pass or score

Comment: I strongly agree. The answer suggesting a map should not be so up-voted, as it's a bad practice in my opinion and even a bad solution to this question as it is not easily sorted as OP requires.